# How do I move JQuery submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am helping a friend with her website and am having an issue with the menu that comes with JQuery.  Actually it is the submenu.  It is appearing behind an overlapping div.  I have tried using position in css but to no avail.  This is a demo of what is happening.  www.hvactechhelp.com/Ashley

Any help would be appreciated.

Just to clarify.  I need the submenu to appear above the buttons on the page.  Z-Index would put the submenu on top.

This is the HTML  The css is the standard jquery-ui.css

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="l_content"> 

    <ul id="menu">

      <li><img src="images/nav-r1.gif" width="201" height="32" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/nav2.gif" width="200" height="32" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/nav3.gif" width="200" height="32" />

        <ul>
           <li><a href="Untitled-3.html"><img src="images/GDsub-r1.png" width="200" height="40"    /></a></li>
           <li><a href="Untitled-3.html"><img src="images/GDsub-r2.png" width="200" height="40" /></a></li>
           <li><a href="Untitled-3.html"><img src="images/GDsub-r3.png" width="200" height="40" /></a></li>
           <li><a href="Untitled-3.html"><img src="images/GDsub-r4.png" width="200" height="40" /></a></li>
           <li><a href="Untitled-3.html"><img src="images/GDsub-r5.png" width="200" height="40" /></a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><img src="images/nav4.gif" width="200" height="32" /></li>
     <li><img src="images/nav5.gif" width="200" height="40" /></li>

    </ul>

  </div>


  <div class="r_content"></div>


</div>
```

Comment: Try changing the z-index instead of the position.

Comment: That would get it on top of the buttons below, but I need it to be above the buttons.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Some source code would help...

Comment: Now some proper code indentation would help...

Comment: If i understand well, you want that, when the mouse hovers the 3rd li in your menu, the sub menu opens and pushes down the following li instead of overlapping them right ?

Comment: No I just need the submenu that appears to the right to move up.   Maybe 30px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your submenu unordered list  tag has inline style with property `top:10px` . Change this to `top:-30px`.

This should shift the submenu above your footer.

Comment: Is that in Jquerry css.  Don't have that in my html.

Comment: Nope, does not look like its part of Jquery CSS. iT looks like separate inline style applied to your submenu. I am looking at the link for the web site you provided in the question.`display: block;top: 10px;left: 202px;` .This is the inline style applied to your submenu and changing the top property to what I suggested shifts the submenu  position above the footer.

Comment: Must be dynamically added with the jquerry-ui.js.   I will search.

Comment: Instead of modifying JQuery UI stuff I would suggest add some css to your submenu `<ul>` tag to make the top property to the desired value.

Comment: How do I make the new css override the inline that the script is inputing?

Comment: Try adding style="top:-30px;" to ur submenu ul tag and let me know if it works. If it does you can later move this to a class and use it instead of using an inline style.

Comment: Thanks.  Its all in the ordering.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: I would discourage using CSS hacks to circumvent the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Code would make it easier to answer, but a wild guess, add a `z-index` higher that the div to the submenu.